# How to use MATLAB to do screen capture on any where of the screen?

Tags: matlab, screenshot

I did search on MATLAB filexhange.

There is a function called ScreenCapture for download..

I used that function, but the image is not 100% as the screen.

I think that it download grade from 256 bit to 16 bit image.

How I can do screen capture any where of the screen with full color?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution to get 100% of the screen that works by accessing underlying Java to perform <kbd>Prt Scrn</kbd> key action which copies the snapshot of the screen to the clipboard and then you can use [**`imclipboard`**](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28708-imclipboard)(from the File Exchange) to paste that image from clipboard to MATLAB:

```
import java.awt.Robot;     %importing java.awt module from the Robot class
import java.awt.event.*;   %importing classes from java.awt 
tmp = Robot();  
%Performing PrintScreen key action           
tmp.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);   
tmp.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_PRINTSCREEN);
pause(0.1); %just to make sure the screenshot is taken
imdata = imclipboard('paste'); %pasting the image data in MATLAB
```